# Python ldap3 how to do pagination using Reader

Tags: python

See following code:

```py
class SomeClass():

    self.person_cls = ldap3.ObjectDef(['user', 'person', 'organizationalPerson'], self.connection)

    def get_all_users(self):
        log.info('Fetching all users...')
        r = ldap3.Reader(self.connection, self.person_cls, self.root_folder)
        return r.search()
```

This is a very time consuming search to return all users...

There is a pagination documention but not related to the Reader abstraction:

https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searches.html#simple-paged-search

But how do I do it if I am using Reader?

Answer (score 0):

So after reading the source code, there is an undocumented function inside Reader

```py
    def search_paged(self, paged_size, paged_criticality=True, generator=True, attributes=None):
        """Perform a paged search, can be called as an Iterator

        :param attributes: optional attributes to search
        :param paged_size: number of entries returned in each search
        :type paged_size: int
        :param paged_criticality: specify if server must not execute the search if it is not capable of paging searches
        :type paged_criticality: bool
        :param generator: if True the paged searches are executed while generating the entries,
                          if False all the paged searches are execute before returning the generator
        :type generator: bool
        :return: Entries found in search
```

So tested with my code and works fine:

```
class SomeClass():

    self.person_cls = ldap3.ObjectDef(['user', 'person', 'organizationalPerson'], self.connection)

    def get_all_users(self):
        log.info('Fetching all users...')
        r = ldap3.Reader(self.connection, self.person_cls, self.root_folder)
        return r.search_paged(paged_size=50)
```